# Appending correctly with ranges python

Tags: python, list, matrix, append

This is part of a code for transposing matrixes, the function takes one argument, a list of lists. Let's suppose if input is:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

Basically, the output should return

```
[[1, 4, 7],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [3, 6, 9]]
```

And so on for any matrix.
This following code returns

```
def matrix(data)
    column = len(data)
    transposed[0].append(data[0][0])
    transposed[0].append(data[1][0])
    transposed[0].append(data[2][0])
    outputs [1,4,7]
```

However, when I try to make it follow colum length it returns instead

```
   transposed[0].append(data[0:column][0])
   outputs [1,2,3]
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transpose a matrix using the built-in function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip%20function#zip):

```
def transpose(m):
    return zip(*m)
```

From the docs:

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains
>   the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The
>   returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest
>   argument sequence. When there are multiple arguments which are all of
>   the same length, `zip()` is similar to `map()` with an initial argument of
>   `None`. With a single sequence argument, it returns a list of 1-tuples.
>   With no arguments, it returns an empty list.
>
> The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed.
>   This makes possible an idiom for clustering a data series into
>   n-length groups using `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)`.

To make this return a list of lists instead of a list of tuples, return the following list comprehension:

```
[list(r) for r in zip(*m)]
```

Here's how to do it using append:

```
def transpose(m):
    transposed = [[] for _ in range(len(m[0]))]
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for j in range(len(m[0])):
            transposed[j].append(m[i][j])
    return transposed
```

As you can see, using `zip` is much easier. :)

Comment: I officially feel stupid ._. Anyways, how would it work using my syntax?

Comment: @Juanvulcano One second, gotta program it. xD

Comment: @Juanvulcano There we go, I hope that helps.